# How to Create Query message nHaPI

Tags: hl7, nhapi

Hi I am starting to work with HL7 project where in I need to create a new message from the database values. I got the nHAPI project on from the internet and have no idea how to work with this. Any Help in this regards is welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is no documentation provided at the NHAPI website, but there is documentation for the HAPI website here: http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/devbyexample.html .  This website provides examples of how to use HAPI which is based on Java, so if you are using C# you should be able to figure out how to get it to work.

What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Good Luck!

EDIT: http://aurora.regenstrief.org/~gunther/oldhtml/tables.html this link provides the structure of each segment of a message. And what each message type is called.

EDIT: http://fusesource.com/docs/router/2.2/component_ref/_IDU_HL7.html this link provides an example message that is an A19, but it is using the HAPI not the nHAPI.

Comment: Actually I need to create one QRY_A19 query from Database values specifically need to insert Customercode, Hospitalcode, Departmentcode into this query.

Comment: The link that I provded has examples of how to create a message.  The example creates an A01 message, it looks like all you need to do is having the following line in your code:
    using ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v24.message.ADT_A19;
Then you can create an object of Type ADT_A19 and assign each field that you need to assign by getting the data from your database instance.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response and many thanks for the link that provides the HL7 TABLES, but am afraid that ADT_A19 does not exist in the type of the message. I think I need to create the object for class QRY_A19.

Comment: Rakesh, I have googled again and found an example of the HAPI having the A19 type.  Maybe that type has not been ported to nHAPI?  If you found my answer useful at all, please upvote it.  Maybe not accepted because it did not answer the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi There, Thanks for your efforts. I really wanted to upvote the answer by you but since I am new to this site and I need 15 points to upvote any answer.

Comment: Hi AndHeCodedIt, Do you have any link that helps to create sample like given below                                                                          a request to lookup a patient with the patient ID, 0101701234.

MSH|^~\\&|MYSENDER|MYRECEIVER|MYAPPLICATION||200612211200||QRY^A19|1234|P|2.4
QRD|200612211200|R|I|GetPatient|||1^RD|0101701234|DEM||

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have one.  Try googling, otherwise you can see if there are any hl7 or HAPI forums to try your question in.